# Lite-server not working

Tags: javascript, lite-server

I had a project that was previously using lite-server. I can no longer get it to run using

> npm run

I see the following from the console

> PS C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Work\Repos\Homepage_Slider> npm run
>   Lifecycle scripts included in homepage_slider:   test
>       echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1   start
>       lite-server

I don't really understand why this isn't working anymore.

I've tried:

- Updating NPM
- Running lite-server globably
- Make sure package.json is set up correctly

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "homepage_slider",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple slider for homepage",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "lite-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "XXX"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Slider"
  ],
  "author": "XXX",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^6.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm run` is a reserved word for npm itself. Check the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)

What you really need is `npm start` which is a shortcut for `npm run start` which is a shortcut for `npm run-script start`!

Comment: Yep you are completely right. Don't know how I missed it. I will accept the answer when SO allows me.